# Ruby on Rails and Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Can I access main app's ApplicationController in my rails engine?
I want to apply a filter to my app's ApplicationController through an engine.
A bit of code will be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: While you can do this as the accepted answer describe, you should avoid this, since it can lead to unexpected results in other parts of the system that expect ApplicationController to be what it is defined in app/controllers/application_controller.rb. Consider supplying the filter in a class and module in your engine and write the before_filter line in the ApplicationController itself. That provides the same functionality while being much less surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always, in your engine, open the `ApplicationController` and write whatever filter you want. This will be used by your main app automatically after the engine has been loaded.

Example code in your engine for a `set_locale` `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could isolate the functionality with which you wish to enhance your host application's ApplicationController doing the following:

1. Create a controller concern having the filter method.

`Create app/controllers/concerns/filterable.rb`

```
module Concerns::Filterable
  include ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :do_something
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def do_something
    end
  end
end
```

`Create config/initializers/filterable.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ApplicationController.send :include, Concerns::Filterable if defined ApplicationController
end
```

Using the initializer above, we make sure our `Concerns::Filterable` is included every time the 
application is reloaded in development.